# Bug larvae identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image] anybody know what this might be, found in my bed. Pennsylvania, USA . Thanks

Comment: Please see the [tag info for species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) to learn how to make an answerable species-ID question.

Answer (score 1):

That's a silverfish (order Zygentoma) https://bugguide.net/node/view/79 This individual is not in great shape, and probably got crushed, however you can see it had the cerci in its tail. The individual is lacking antennae, which are usually long, but the eyes  are also very characteristic. You can see a similar picture on this thread (https://bedbugger.com/forum/topic/here-we-go-againcame-home-now-and-found-this-id-please-silverfish. They are fairly common in homes and are harmless. They feed on fibers and detritus in your home.

Comment: that certainly doesn't look like any silverfish I've ever seen. Presence of prominent [cerci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercus) is not conclusive evidence of a silverfish. The OP's specimen appears to be a larvae of some type, and silverfish don't have larvae as they undergo [**direct development**](http://www.knowyourinsects.org/glossary.html#DirectDevelopment) vs. [complete metamorphosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holometabolism). Please provide stronger support for your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I stand by my ID, because I've seen exactly specimens of silverfish like that. This is just a mangled specimen, which makes sense because the OP found it on the bed. Also, I know silverfish have direct development (I'm a PhD in Entomology), but you're assuming the OP knows those finer biological details.

Comment: Ok please explicitly explain what characteristics (and /or provide image examples) you've used to make your claim. Currently, it comes across as an unsupported guess. Due to the immense amount of misinformation on the internet, Answers can't be based on expertise alone - you need to expand upon your answer. Regarding biological details, please see [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3970/16866). Thanks.